# How to move an image up and down smoothly with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner in CSS.Is it possible to move an image up and down smoothly with CSS?

Similar to the following link:

....

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? can you provide some code? 2. you'll also need javascript to achieve this

Comment: @Nick - There is no need for JavaScript, this could be done with CSS alone using `@keyframes`.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Well, tell me how..? So far I know you can't calculate the offset in css, **edit: oh.. I tought he meant the background that moves when you scroll, my bad, you're right this can be done with keyframes.**

Comment: @Nick - You don't have to calculate the offset, all you have to do is animate the `margin-top` or `translateY` like the answer below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use CSS3 animations.

***Snippet:***

```css
img {
    -webkit-animation: mover 2s infinite  alternate;
    animation: mover 2s infinite  alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mover {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-20px); }
}
@keyframes mover {
    0% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-20px); }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://app.netbarg.com/img/phone-in-hand-a.png" />
```

Comment: I would add `@-moz-keyframes mover` and `@-o-keyframes mover` just in case. Great solution!